# Search Solution Mongodb lookup and filter fields

Tags: mongodb, filter, lookup

I´m looking a simple solution for my MongoDB Lookup-Problem.

I have two collections:

Disp with the following structure:

```
   {"_id" : ObjectId("5f748869487b4d0013ee50b4"),
"productId": ObjectId("5f9a96f85b909923e8530f0c"),
"subproductId" ObjectId("5e8b3684a82c2a00134e507a"),
},
{"_id" : ObjectId("5f74870e487b4d0013ee50b3"),
"productId": ObjectId("5f7b4b17e8ec6a00158bb5d8"),
"subproductId" ObjectId("5f78303a82f45e0013afebc1"),
}
```

and a Collection "Product with the following structure:

```
{_id: ObjectId("5f9a96f85b909923e8530f0c"),
   subproduct: [ {
        _id:ObjectId("5e8b3684a82c2a00134e507a"),
         title: "Test"
         },
        {_id: ObjectId("5f369a94018c040013c76ede"),
         title: "Test 1"}
      ]},
{_id:ObjectId("5f7b4b17e8ec6a00158bb5d8"),
        subproduct: [ {
             _id: ObjectId("5f7b43efe8ec6a00158bb5cc"),
              title: "Test3"
        }, {
             _id: ObjectId("5f78303a82f45e0013afebc1"),
             title: "Test 4"}
   ]
```

As you can see I have to do a lookup to an array "subproduct" with its ObjectID.
But if I do a normal lookup I will receice all other array-elements as well.

How do I filter the result so that the result will be only the subproduct-array element it matches.
Same as an inner join.

My expected result will be:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5f748869487b4d0013ee50b4"),
"productId": ObjectId("5f9a96f85b909923e8530f0c"),
"subproductId" ObjectId("5e8b3684a82c2a00134e507a"),
"subproduct": {
      _id:ObjectId("5e8b3684a82c2a00134e507a"),
      title: "Test"
},
{"_id" : ObjectId("5f74870e487b4d0013ee50b3"),
"productId": ObjectId("5f7b4b17e8ec6a00158bb5d8"),
"subproductId" ObjectId("5f78303a82f45e0013afebc1"),
},
"subproduct": {
      _id: ObjectId("5f78303a82f45e0013afebc1"),
      title: "Test 4"
},
```

Thx,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```js
db.disp.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "let": {
        subprodId: "$subproductId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$subproduct"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$subprodId",
                "$subproduct._id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "subDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$subDetails"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      productId: 1,
      subproductId: 1,
      subproduct: {
        _id: "$subDetails.subproduct._id",
        title: "$subDetails.subproduct.title"
      }
    }
  }
])
```